# high cache size for RDD in apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am reading a textfile of ~20MB consisting of rows of space separated integers, convert to RDD and cache it. On caching I observed, it consumed ~200MB on RAM!
I don't understand why it is consuming such high RAM (x10) for caching ?

```
val filea = sc.textFile("a.txt")
val fileamapped = filea.map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt)) 
fileamapped.persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
fileamapped.collect()
```

I am running Spark in local interactive mode (spark-shell) and reading datafile from HDFS.

Questions

1. Reasons behind high RAM use for caching?
2. Is there a way I can directly read integers from the file, sc.textFile gives me RDD[String].
3. I checked fileamapped with estimate() method and it shows ~64MB size, would it be JAVA component sizes?

thanks,

Comment: How are you observing the cache memory size?

Comment: free mem -m on local machine before and after collect() call.

Comment: cluster web UI is not working so can't see cache size in there.